# update data with 2 parameters codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a function in my model like this which I I think update a data with the following rider_id and vehicle id in db.

```
 public function makeVehicleActive($rider_id,  $vehicle_pk)
  {
    $this->db->where('rider_id', $rider_id);
    $this->db->update('rider_vehicles', ['is_active' => 0]);

    $this->db->where('id', $vehicle_pk);
    return $this->db->update('rider_vehicles', ['is_active' => 1]);
  }
```

how can I implement this on a controller and view?
really needed your help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example will help you:

```php
$data = array(
    'title' => $title,
    'name' => $name,
    'date' => $date
);

$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->update('mytable', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep those 2 variables in an array then run the update query.

Example:

```
    $data = array(
        'first_date' => 'data1', 
        'second_data' => 'data2'
    );
    
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('table', $data);
```